# How to install previous version of package by console on cygwin?

Tags: svn, cygwin

I need to write a script that deploy many cygwin applications with svn-1.6-17. All my attempts were finished by installing or svn-1.7, or nothing.

I tried to install subversion, subversion-1.6, subversion-1.6-17. It all was useless.

How I can install previous version of package by console on cygwin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just went through this and I'm adding this to help the next person. Note: this same technique will probably work for any Cygwin package.

We have a third party product that talks directly to the subversion server, but keeps its directories in the 1.6 format. If the local directories are updated, the tool breaks. But I needed a way to do a `svn cleanup` for times when the tool got in a bad state.

Here's how I went about doing this:

- [Cygwin Time Machine](http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/cygwin/timemachine.html) at crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org maintains archives of previous releases. Each release consists of a setup.bz2 (the compressed setup.ini file) and a collection of related archives for the packages of that release.
- I searched the [cygwin-announce](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/) mailinglist for updates of subversion. The last update for 1.6 was June 10, 2011.
- Next, I walked through the crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org [indexes of previous releases](http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/index.html) from that date until I found the last release of svn 1.6, It was the July 1, 2011 release.
- I downloaded setup.bz2 from the corresponding directory on crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat (in this case: http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2011/07/01/062011/setup.bz2). I used bunzip2 to unpack setup.bz2 to a simple text file. I found the entry for subversion and copied the path of the install tarball (release/subversion/subversion-1.6.17-1.tar.bz2). The section you're looking for looks like this:

  `@ subversion
  sdesc: "A version control system"
  ldesc: "Subversion is a version control system that aims to be a compelling
  replacement for CVS in the open source community"
  category: Devel
  requires: libapr1 libaprutil1 libdb4.5 libexpat1 libgcc1 libintl8 libneon27 libsasl2 libserf0_1 libsqlite3_0 zlib0 cygwin
  version: 1.6.17-1
  install: release/subversion/subversion-1.6.17-1.tar.bz2 775392 ed0c4a3cc494564c0539dffedcd5e8b6
  source: release/subversion/subversion-1.6.17-1-src.tar.bz2 5551632 1b41eede9a14ea4cedcc462b06b1f7cb
  [prev]
  version: 1.6.16-1
  install: release/subversion/subversion-1.6.16-1.tar.bz2 1476151 ecbc29b1e1d9694bf8792e3871efa5f8
  source: release/subversion/subversion-1.6.16-1-src.tar.bz2 5557232 cb12425d2345a57341f16ad0ff559b84`
- We're interested in this line that gives the relative path to the 1.6 svn tarball:

  `install: release/subversion/subversion-1.6.17-1.tar.bz2 775392`
- I retrieved the tarball for subversion and extracted it to a temporary directory (temp). I moved the contents of temp/usr/bin to a svn16 directory.

Now, I can prepend that directory to the search path and get the functionality of svn 1.6 like so:

```
PATH=~/svn16:$PATH svn up
```

**Note:** It looks like the Cygwin Time Machine no longer allows directory browsing. This means you'll need to start from the [root](http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html) an dig a bit to find a package.

Updated with links as I just needed to do this again.

**Note 2:** Updated links to crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat

Comment: I could not find setup.bz2 at ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2011/07/01/062011 could you provide links for exact file locations. Also I tried using setup.exe as mentioned in time machine page but I get error like setup.ini not found.

Comment: +7, if I could.  Holy crap, the Internet is a better place with this answer.

Comment: Please note: The **Cygwin Time Machine** has moved! Please view the new site at [http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html].  Also note that the old FTP urls have been converted to HTTP urls with a different hostname prefix such as **(http://ctm.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/...)**

Comment: As we now know, [fruitbats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabat#As_disease_reservoirs) are more dangerous than dragons.

Answer (score 7):

1) Download a `subversion` package from a download site offered by the `cygwin` installer.
[I personally took it from here (64 bit version)](http://mirror.dotsrc.org/cygwin/x86_64/release/subversion/)  and saved it into an empty directory.

EDIT: If you want the 32-bit version, just remov the "_64" from the URL.

[image: Choose A Download site]

2) Start the `cygwin` installer and choose `Install from Local Directory` when it asks to choose from a download source.

3) Locate everything related to `subversion`. Uninstall the unwanted version and install the old one. The newer version is already uninstalled on the image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but i'm looking for non-GUI solution. Because i need to write a python scripts to deploy cygwin on many pc.