# Cygwin - Installing a specific package version using the commandline installer

Tags: cygwin

Using the commandline installer, one can easily install Cygwin with a list of wanted packages like so

```
setup-x86.exe -q -p='tar,sed,<more packages>'
```

Is it also possible to fix the version of the packages, something like

```
setup-x86.exe -q -p='tar:1.2.3,sed,<more packages>'
```

(this obviously doesn't work)?

Comment: It looks like you can add some regex in the `-p`: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygcheck

Comment: Why don't you use `apt-cyg` for all command-line package installation?

Comment: You might be interested by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13020130/14673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is function that Cygwin's installer now provides.  By default, when running from the command line, it will install the latest version of each package, but you can specify a version with `=`. For example:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -P git=2.35.0-1,vim
```

will install the latest version of Vim, and version 2.35.0-1 of Git.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your query is, **No**. Cygwin's `setup -x86.exe` does not give you the flexibility to specify version names along with package names. As per the official doc :

> The basic reason for not having a more full-featured package manager is that such a program would need full access to all of Cygwin's POSIX functionality. That is, however, difficult to provide in a Cygwin-free environment, such as exists on first installation. Additionally, Windows does not easily allow overwriting of in-use executables so installing a new version of the Cygwin DLL while a package manager is using the DLL is problematic

There are however a couple of workarounds if you want to download a specific package:

1. Locate a cygwin mirror that hosts the specific version. Google for your version, and if you find a mirror hosting that version, simply use that mirror before running  `setup -x86.exe`. [[**source**]](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.old-versions)
2. Maintain a local pacakge repository and use the commandline options `-q -L -l x:\cygwin-local\`, where your downloaded package tree is in `x:\cygwin-local\`  [[**source**]](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.setup.automated) . You can learn how to build and maitain packages [here](https://cygwin.com/setup.html)
3. Compile and install the package after you've set up cygwin using `make`.