# Linking libxml with MinGW using OMNETPP shell on windows 10

Tags: windows, mingw, posix, omnet++, libxml2

How can I link libxml on MinGW when using an omnetpp shell?

I am using omnetpp on a windows 10 machine.
My problem happens when I am trying to install the 3rd party package from [here](https://github.com/Mellanox/DCTrafficGen/tree/master)
I think that there is a problem in the Makefile failing to locate the libxml library
Following Rudi's answer (following the question) I changed the Makefile libxml path to `I/mingw64/include/libxml2` but I still
get a `undefined reference to 'xmlFunctionName'` error (for many function names)

I tried to isolate the problem and to compile a [sample of code from libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/tree2.c)
Following the compilation guide:
 using `` gcc `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -o tree2 tree2.c ``
I got a `fatal error: 'libxml/parser.h' file not found`
When I replaced `xml2-config --cflags --libs` with `-I/mingw64/include/libxml2`
I got the same error as before `undefined reference to 'xmlFunctionName'`

what can I do to resolve that issue?

Comment: I suggest looking for solution how to add a 3rd party libraries to **MinGW**, not for OMNeT++.

Comment: But this is not any 3rd party package on just a MinGW compiler but a specific problem. I did searched for adding 3rd party libraries to MinGW, found & followed the steps  [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985764/how-to-add-3rd-party-libraries-to-mingw). the solution is not the same for all POSIX simulator on windows, for example, Cygwin [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699972/how-to-install-previous-version-of-package-by-console-on-cygwin) is not relevant for me.

Comment: @JerzyD. the question has been edited

Answer (score 1):

To this specific problem: libxml2 is actually already present as OMNET 5.x also uses it. All dependencies and tools are available in the `tools/win64/mingw64` directory. The problem is that (for unknown reasons) the include file of the `include/libxml2/libxml` folder. The configure script correctly detects this and makes it available in the `Makefile.inc` as `XML_CFLAGS= = -I/mingw64/include/libxml2`

This must be added to the compiler flags for each file where you want to use the XML parser. (the library files are in the `/mingw64/lib` folder) so those are detected and can be used without additional config.

Generally, third party libraries should be available in the `/mingw64/include` and `/mingw64/lib` folders. You can either copy them manually there or try to install it with the mingw package manager (however that will most likely ruin your omnet installation as mingw64 is not particularly consistent and it is a rolling release - i.e. this is highly not recommended).

Comment: changing to ```I/mingw64/include/libxml2``` did fix the ```file not found``` error but I get a ```undefined reference to xml_FunctionName``` it seems like a linker problem, any idea how to fix it?